# Java code to swift converter

Tags: java, swift

I'm developing in swift for iOS and i would like to convert my Utils library in java to swift.
Is there any online converter to convert simple java code into swift code?

Comment: I couldn't find any tools for this purpose, so I [wrote a translator](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%5Cnpublic%20static%20int%20add(int%20a%2C%20int%20b)%7B%5Cnwhile(a%20%3C%203)%7Ba%20%3D%20a%2B1%3B%7D%20%20%20%5Cnif(a%3E4)%7B%5Cnreturn%20a%2Bb%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cnelse%20if(a%3C5)%7Breturn%20a-b%3B%7D%5Cn%5Cnelse%7Breturn%20a*b%3B%7D%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22java%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22swift%22%7D) to convert a small subset of Java into Swift.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know about a java to swift converter, however, Google developed a Java to objective-C converter, you can find it at https://github.com/google/j2objc

You can use objective c files together with swift files in one project. I think this is the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try doing it in two steps. Java -> objective-C --> Swift.

Comment: I'm [working on a Java -> Swift converter](https://github.com/jarble/transpiler) now. It's not quite finished, but it can translate a small subset of Java into several other programming languages.

Comment: so, if you use this answer and get objective-c, you can use this site to convert to swift: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/

Comment: Say, has anyone seen a "swift TO java" convertor, as a curiosity?

Comment: @quemeful I also found a Java-to-Swift converter called [J2swift](https://github.com/patniemeyer/j2swift).